# how to create MVC for search in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I am very new to CodeIgniter, which has been very hard for me to learn so far. I mostly never work with frameworks and this is my first time.

I understand MVC but I really don't know how to create a search, even just a basic one: I just want someone to send a word in an input and search it in my database (with Ajax or not) and give the answer back. Could anyone help me with some ideas for how I should proceed? I understand that in the view I will put my divs, inputs and more, and in the controller I will call my functions that will interact with my model. I'm struggling with how to integrate them on CI though because the view is actually filled via the controller and I believe I can't use the functions of from it in the view.

Any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [site search with codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817864/site-search-with-codeigniter)

Comment: *(tutorial)* http://devsnippets.com/article/getting-started-with-codeigniter-and-how-to-create-all-those-great-apps.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Start by creating a controller that will be handling the search requests and displaying the search page, followed by the search-term passed to the model for database lookup (and sending it back to the controller). The controller will pass it to the view.

A little example;

**The Controller**

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->model('search_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('search_form');
    }

    public function execute_search()
    {
        // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

        // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results($search_term);

        // Pass the results to the view.
        $this->load->view('search_results',$data);
    }

}
```

**The Model**

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_results($search_term='default')
    {
        // Use the Active Record class for safer queries.
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('members');
        $this->db->like('username',$search_term);

        // Execute the query.
        $query = $this->db->get();

        // Return the results.
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

**The view for displaying the search form**

```
<?php
    echo form_open('search/execute_search');

    echo form_input(array('name'=>'search'));

    echo form_submit('search_submit','Submit');


?>
```

**The View for displaying results**

```
<div>
    <?php
        // List up all results.
        foreach ($results as $val)
        {
            echo $val['username'];
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, most likely you will use post method instead of get.
So, in the search form, make sure that you are using post method.

for example

View:

```
<form action="<?=site_url('search_controller/search_function_in_controller')?>" method="post">
  search: <input type="text" name="keyword" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
<?php
class Search_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function search_function_in_controller()
    {
            $keyword = $_POST['keyword']; // you can also use $this->input->post('keyword');
            $this->load->model('Search_model');
            $data['search_result'] = $this->search_model->search_user($keyword);
            $this->load->view('search_result', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
<?php
class Searchmodel extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('first_name',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}

?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
Class Search extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('searchmodel');

    }


    function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword=$this->input->post('submit');
        $data['users']=$this->searchmodel->search($keyword);

        $this->load->view('user/view', $data);

    }
}
?>
```

**View**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="<?php echo site_url().'/search/search_keyword';?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search by firstname">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" >Search</button>
</form>
```